# SQLAlchemy Setup for Microsoft SQL Server 18 ODBC

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm actually asking this question as I have recently struggled to get SQLAlchemy working with SQL Server ODBC Driver 18 on a Mac and have not seen an up-to-date description that worked.

NB: `'TrustServerCertificate': 'yes'` is very key for a lot of setups and knowing where and how to express it in the connection string is not immediately obvious.

This works (as @ 7 Sep 2022) with the MSSQL ODBC driver instructions at: [Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (macOS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver16#microsoft-odbc-18)

Answer (score 1):

````
constring = f"mssql+pyodbc://{username}:{password}@{server}/{database}?driver={driver}"
print (f"Connection String: {constring}")
dbEngine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(constring, fast_executemany=True, connect_args={'connect_timeout': 10, 'TrustServerCertificate': 'yes'}, echo=False) 
try:
    with dbEngine.connect() as con:
        con.execute("SELECT 1")
    print('SQLAlchemy engine is valid')
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Engine invalid: {str(e)}')```
````

Answer (score 0):

add `&TrustServerCertificate=yes` with the connection URL:

```
f"mssql://{User}:{Password}@{Server}/{Database}?driver={Driver}&TrustServerCertificate=yes"
```